# How to improve BigQuery performance for table scans?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with some 80 million records of financial transactions.  I want to find every transaction above $100 million.  This query takes about 3 seconds, which will not work for my BI tool.

```
% time bq query --nouse_cache 'select * from kc_imports.all WHERE VALUE > 100000000'
```

The time results are:

```
0.35s user 
0.10s system 
15% cpu 
2.899 total
```

Is there any way to drastically improve the time to complete the query?  If so, what are some tips?   Does Google Cloud provide some type of map-reduce tools perhaps?

I should note here that subsequent query might be different, eg. I may want to also search for all transactions below $500.

Comment: If you can, share your query.

Comment: You should show your query - otherwise it is just abstact question that has no practical answer. So please edit your question to show a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [ask].

Comment: I added my findings in an answer below - if you have any job id the team can analyze the exact query and what's happening behind.

Comment: Fair comments, my apologies.  I will add my code once I have reviewed @FelipeHoffa 's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's run some queries over a public table with >5 billion rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201605] 
WHERE requests>1000
```

This query took 6.1s to run over 357 GB. How can we make it faster?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201605] 
  WHERE requests>1000
)
```

5.8s, over 38.6 GB. It took about the same time, but it queried way less data (cheaper query) when selecting only one column (BigQuery realizes that the only needed column to get this result is `requests`).

```
SELECT *
FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201605] 
WHERE requests>1000
LIMIT 500
```

1.7s, over 357 GB. Almost the same query as the first one, but way faster when we added the LIMIT. Why? As BigQuery divides the task between many workers, performance will be limited by the slowest one. If we LIMIT the results to 500, BigQuery doesn't need to wait for all of the workers to return.

An interesting result here: The question mentions that it took 6 seconds to scan 80 million rows. In this example I scanned >5 billion rows in 6 seconds. That's an interesting scalability display on how BigQuery would deal with a 100 times more data.

Other interesting results:

```
SELECT SUM(requests)
FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201105]
```

1.6s, 4.4 billion rows.

```
SELECT SUM(requests)
FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201306]
```

1.8s, 5.4 billion rows.

```
SELECT SUM(requests)
FROM [fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_201605]
```

5.3s, 5.1 billion rows.

We are witnessing here some skew in the data storage - these tables are very similar to each other, but something is different about the 201605 one that is giving me slower results than every other table. Normally I would expect BigQuery to constantly optimize how data is stored - automatically and without the need to execute anything (https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format).

Comment: Hi Felipe, I watch you in many videos on Youtube, so I really appreciate your quick and thorough answers. :)

Comment: What are the square brackets for?  Is is because underscore is not allowed in SQL?

Comment: `undescore` IS allowed. `Hyphen` IS NOT allowed in table reference but is part here of project fh-bigquery

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest few things, depending on how you query your data:

- scan less data by limiting the query to only columns which you really need.
- Maximize the usage of cache (don't change the data too frequently in the table you query)
- As part of your data loading process, create separate table for transactions over 100M or any other value you need. This will limit the number of records BQ needs to scan when you are looking for certain records of these transactions)
- Avoid non-deterministic queries, for example things like NOW() or TODAY() because they are not cacheable.
- Consider using daily partitioned tables [1] because it can limit the amount of data to be scanned as well (if you look for transactions between two dates)
- Consider using Table Decorators [2], especially if you need to query only recent data (i.e. last 10 minutes or last hour)
- If you're using REGEXP_MATCH(), consider using CONTAINS() instead, where possible..
- Keep query result < 128MB, otherwise it won’t get cached as well

Finally, the real power of BigQuery us that while your data grow, your query time will increase but in much smaller scale. However, BigQuery really shines with really big datasets but it's not a real-time query engine - it's analytical database. If you need 1s or sub-second responses, you will need additional caching layer on top of BigQuery.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators

Comment: Interesting suggestions, but I'm not sure I want to cache the queries, since it may only be one end user of thousands who want to ask the question that the query caches.  The 999 other users may want to ask something completely different of the data that the cached data will not address. For this same reason, a separate table is not an option.  Will now explore your other suggestions. Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM KcTrade:kc_imports.all.VALUE WHERE VALUE > 100000000;
```

Few thoughts based on your actual example

1. Using `SELECT *` forces scanning of all columns of your table! Do you really need all? Specifying only fields/column you need can drastically improve performance.
2. Do you need all rows? Using `LIMIT` can extremely improve performance!
3. Finally! what actually you do in your BI tool? 
   Most likely some sort of aggregation/stats/etc.
   Why not to implement logic here and output just result.
   Output of heavy volumed transactional raw data by itself is timeconsuming - whereas output of low volumed aggregational data is fast

> - With regards to limit, I can't do it, I need all the records.
> - Because the tool needs to support arbitrary exploration of the entire dataset

The main problem with your specific use case - is that it is not what BigQuery is for!

> Google BigQuery is a web service that lets you do interactive analysis
>   of massive datasets—up to billions of rows. Scalable and easy to use,
>   BigQuery lets developers and businesses tap into powerful data
>   analytics on demand.

BigQuery is a tool by itself to do `interactive analysis of massive datasets`!
So, instead of using its power - your use case uses BigQuery only as data store. You might consider some other DB for this, with perks like indexing, etc.

Just wanted to share my thoughts on it

Comment: 1.  I tried your suggestion with `% time bq query --nouse_cache 'select VALUE  from kc_imports.all WHERE VALUE > 100000000'`  but it had no effect on the time.  2.  With regards to limit, I can't do it, I need all the records. 3. Because the tool needs to support arbitrary exploration of  the entire dataset.

Comment: understood and result is mostly expected. see addition to my answer

Comment: "Google BigQuery is a web service that lets you do interactive analysis of massive datasets"  - that's exactly what I need to do, so I'm not sure why you say my use case is not a fit.   Yes, indexing is a nice perk.  I will try Google CloudSQL and see what type of speeds I get.  What I really need is an OLAP cube I suppose

Comment: it doesn't look to me this way. instead of doing analysis within BigQuery - you just trying to get out all qualified transactions and then analyse it in some external tool. That is why I "said" this way! And of course, I tried to emphasise the point so I might overstated it a little. But I still after this point! Though, I can be wrong :o) Don't kill the messenger anyway! :o)

Comment: Hi Mikhael, you are 100% right about not using * in my queries. I just discovered that my original query processed 5.2 Gigabytes of data, but when I selected only VALUE, it dropped down to 632MB.   This information is available in the BigQuery web interface.  From this I can extrapolate that the way to get blazing speed is to reorganize my data to be more columnar.  Less rows and more columns should do the trick.

Comment: super. i am glad we get to positive conclusion / takeout here :o)

Comment: btw. the same recomendation - `limiting the query to only columns which you really need` you can find in others (by Felipe and by DoIT International) answers